# Java - How to efficiently show words from a words list as you type

Tags: java, iterator, treeset, startswith

I made a small Java program that loads a words list from a txt file which user chooses and stores it word-by-word in a TreeSet.
Now I need to write a function that, whenever user types something into a text field (keyPressed), a function gets called and it finds/returns all words in this TreeSet that are beginning with letters that user typed in.
I am new to using Sets so my solution would be to iterate from the first to the last element in the set and printing out the ones that satisfy the criteria:

```
Iterator <String>itr = dictionary.iterator();
String currentWord;
String tempUserInput = "av"; // Temporary, to simulate user input
while(itr.hasNext()){
   currentWord = itr.next();
   if (currentWord.startsWith(tempUserInput)) {
      System.out.println(currentWord); // Temporary, to simulate output
   }
}
```

This works properly but, since it needs to pass over 300000 words for a return value, my question is: Is there a more efficient solution to this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Best stolution is to use a [**trie**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) which is a suitable data structure for your problem. It is meant to be used to lower complexity while working of elements (usually strings) that share prefixes.

Actually with some working I guess you could use a TreeSet by tricking the

```
public NavigableSet<E> subSet(E fromElement, boolean fromInclusive, E toElement, boolean toInclusive)
```

This could work by passing as fromElement the string which is currently typed and as the toElement the same string with added enough `'z'` characters as the longest string in the set (this length could be calculated while populating the `TreeSet`). Eg:

```
subSet("foo", true, "foozzzzzzzz", true);
```

Comment: subSet("foo", true, "foo"+"\ufffd", false); covers every cases.